# Is there any framework that allow us to create web application update package that work on web?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, iis-7

I need to deploy my ASP.NET application to many locations. I want some library/framework that can deploy all changed files/database/config to target machine **by installing with web application itself**.

Web application will notify admin of web application that there is some update and admin can **click to update application on that website**.

[image]

PS. For web application, it's quite simpler than windows application because there are only few location that need to update (File & Folder, Database and merge configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a Setup file by using such a program like [installshield](http://www.installshield.com/)

Comment: But admin cannot run it via web application because InstallShield installation package is windows application not web application.

Comment: no you cannot run it through web, you need to run it on the system, and the MSI will configure the web site in IIS and database in sql server